# Redis publish to one client

Tags: redis

Is it possible to publish a message to only one client subscribed to channel? I know how to get the address (client list). Is it possible to get the address and publish to only that client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Redis you publish to a channel, not to a subscriber. 
So the only way should be having one channel per client. 
You can probably have one common channel to share the address, and then use the addresses as the channels name.

http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

As an example, using C# and StackExchange.Redis library:

```
//SERVER
var cnn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
var sub = cnn.GetSubscriber();
sub.Subscribe("common", (channel, value) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("SERVER Received in common: {0}", value);
    sub.Publish("channel:" + value, "private from server to " + value);
});

//CLIENT
var cnn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
var address = "client1";
var sub = cnn.GetSubscriber();
sub.Subscribe("channel:" + address, (channel, value) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Private: {0}", value);

});
sub.Publish("common", address);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: what I was trying to do was to have all subscribers listen but only one handle the message. The way I did this was create a stack in redis and have all subscribe to a key's list command notifications. So I would RPUSH a new value onto the key, the subscribers would get the keyspace notification and the fist to LPOP the value would handle it.